# Cloning and deploying existing Linux builds via Chef, Puppet, etc

Tags: linux, puppet, chef

Is Chef, Puppet, etc able to be pointed at an existing Linux server and suck down 100% of the 'stuff' that would be required to build the server OS/package-versions/custom-files/etc including the build order?

(Guessing not, but believe I was lead to believe this from a talk I heard last year.)

Comment: +1 for the answer pointing to blueprint.  The difference between the two tools is that Chef takes a blank server and describes how to make it into what you want, and blueprint takes what you already have and figures out how to build it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tool you're looking for is [blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/).

Comment: Thanks, possible [linking to the other questions related to blueprint](http://serverfault.com/search?q=blueprint) might be of use to someone that runs across this page.